# Is there a jQuery plugin similar to the SproutCore PickerPane?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Looking to achieve a similar effect to clicking on the SC.PickerPane.Pointer button on this page:  http://demo.sproutcore.com/sample_controls/.  I don't want to reinvent the wheel if I don't need to, but I'm having trouble even coming up with a relevant term to search for this under.  Anyone have any suggestions or at least know a more common name for this effect?

Comment: a tooltip with html or ajax-loaded content inside it may serve the same purpose: one example (click a link) http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery popup bubble seems to do some of this.

http://www.vegabit.com/jquery_bubble_popup_v2/

You can have it work on click instead of mouseOver\mouseOut; Have a look at the shopping cart demo and click some buttons:

http://www.vegabit.com/Examples/add-to-shopping-cart-ecommerce.html#null